# How to stagger cron jobs in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have roughly 20 cronjobs in Kubernetes that handle various tasks at specific time intervals. Currently there's a fair bit of overlap causing usage of resources to spike, opposed to the usage graph being more flat.

Below is a rough example of one of my cronjobs:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: cronjob
metadata:
  name: my-task
spec:
  schedule: "*/20 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  suspend: false
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 1
      ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 900
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: my-task-account
          containers:
          - name: my-task
            image: 12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-task:latest
            command: ["/bin/sh"]
            args:
              - -c
              - >-
                  python3 my-task.py
            resources:
              requests:
                memory: "3Gi"
                cpu: "800m"
              limits:
                memory: "5Gi"
                cpu: "1500m"
          restartPolicy: Never
```

Is there a way to stagger my jobs so that they aren't all running concurrently?

ie.

- job 1 starts at 12:00 with next run at 12:20
- job 2 starts at 12:01 with next run at 12:21
- job 3 starts at 12:02 with next run at 12:22
- job 4 starts at 12:03 with next run at 12:23

A solution where this is handled automatically would be 1st prize however a manually configured solution would also suffice.

Comment: I am not sure. but "ResourceQuota"  with the max running pod in one time can be configured for your corn jobs.  Also, this configuration is more completed about scheduling, and need deep dive into it.

Comment: There is no built-in functionality to trigger CronJobs on completion in Kubernetes - why not setting specific schedule for CronJobs to start exactly 2 minutes apart from each other with 20 min cycle?

Comment: @anarxz I've played around with the cron timing and maybe i'm just dense but I can't seem to get this right. what would that cron look like? 

I've made some improvements in the code to reduce its dependence on resources which is always good but that won't be enough as we scale up.

Comment: @DamianJacobs As far as I understood, all your jobs are configured separately, you can set specific schedule for each of them, e.g. for job 1 that starts at 12:00 with next run at 12:20 it can set up like this:
spec:
  schedule: "0,20 12 * * *"
and correspondingly for job 2:

spec:
  schedule: "01,21 12 * * *"

Answer (score 1):

**Posting my comment as the answer for better visibility.**

As far as I understood, all your jobs are configured separately, you can set specific schedule for each of them, e.g. for job 1 that starts at 12:00 with next run at 12:20 it can set up like this:

```
spec:
  schedule: "0,20 12 * * *"
```

and correspondingly for job 2:

```
spec:
  schedule: "01,21 12 * * *"
```